# How does google container engines load balancer interact with replication controllers?

Tags: google-app-engine, load-balancing

I've read through the google container engine and load balancer docs.

What I've understood:

- I can encapsulated common pods into one replication controller
- I can add network load balancing very easily to my container engine app

Given I have various services sitting behind a nginx reverse proxy.

What I want to say: This is my set of services behind nginx. Please push them to each node and connect nginx to the load balancer. Hence, when one node fails it can serve the others and so on.

Questions:

1. Do I understand the idea of load balancers and replication controllers in that context correctly?
2. If yes, do I assume right that only the frontend parts of the application go into the replication controller while non-replica services (such as the postgres database or the redis cache) are pushed into a service?
3. How would I set that up? I do not find a point in the docs where it actually connects a load balancer to my container entrypoints.

In general I'm a bit new to the concepts and may struggle with basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get your idea behind your first question. This is how I see this:

- The loadbalancer is just used to open your service to the outside, to set a public IP to your nginx pods in your case. Here is how this works (also the answer to your question 3.): https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/load-balancer
- The replication controller is used to make sur you have always the right number of pods running for the associated pod. So the best way to make any pod run indefinitely is in this context. To answer your question 2., I would make sur that all your pods run with an associated replication controller, postgres db and redis included, just to be certain that you have always an instance of them running.
- The service makes it easy to communicate between "internal" pods, and also has some kind of internal load balancing if the associated pod is replicated. In your case, your db and redis pods (each controlled by a replication controller) will indeed have to be managed also by a service to make them available to your nginx pods.

If you want an example of a complete "stack" running I would suggest this link: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook even if it is quite simple you can get the main ideas behind all this.

Comment: What I meant is: How do I actually get "load balancing", if i have a service with a public ip and this service has two replicas, will kubernetes automatically start to load balance between those?

Comment: If you look at this link: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/load-balancer
    ```Traffic is sent to nodes in the cluster in round-robin order.```